# How can I delete contact relationships in Siri?

Tags: iphone, siri

Today something really stupid happened to me. To show the new iPhone I gave it to a friend at work. He activated Siri and said:

"Call my father"

Siri said : "Who is your father?"

My friend said his name and since he was in the address book contacts the phone called his number. Now every time I say "Call my father" my friends number is called. How can I delete this "relationship" and where is it stored?

Comment: Cue Maury Povich. Or Darth Vader.

Answer (score 4):

Tell Siri "My father is XYZ" and let it make the change for you.

Answer (score 3):

According to this [Apple discussion forum](https://discussions.apple.com/message/16384574#16384574), the way to modify the contact is:

1. Go to **Settings**->**General**->**Siri**
2. Tap '**My Info**'
3. Change the wrong profile to the correct contact

Alternately, you can also follow the instructions from [this post](http://forums.macrumors.com/showpost.php?p=13619344&postcount=4):

> Set up a contact for yourself and edit it to add a field
>   "relationship" or something like that. Then you can add mother,
>   brother, etc. Next time you tell siri to "send text to your mom it
>   will know.

Other useful Siri tips can be found [here](http://www.tipb.com/2011/10/18/daily-tip-create-relationship-contact-siri/).

Answer (score 3):

1. Make sure your "My Info" setting in Siri is correctly set to your contact.
2. Find your own contact info and click Edit.
3. scroll down till you see the "father" field.
4. Click the red delete button next to the father field or change it your fathers contact.

<sub>(evidently i'm not cool enough for images yet, sorry)</sub>

Answer (score 0):

Go to your own name in you 'contacts' and your Siri created relationships are all there. You can edit left-swipe them to delete. Then you can give Siri the correct info

Answer (score 0):

Ask Siri how do you know my name? He will tell you with your profile. Click on it and choose edit and then delete the wrong information you gave him.
Very easy...

Answer (score 0):

Find your name in your contacts, then scroll down. You will see a list of family and names that describes the relationship, there you can edit and delete.